# freepbx over openvpn network

Tags: openvpn, freepbx

I am using OpenVPN to access my internal network. I have FreePBX for my SIP phones. I have a soft phone on my cell phone when I am on my WiFi the soft phone works great. When I leave WiFi and go to VPN I can connect to my PBX. I have audio going from my soft phone to any phone on my network. I do not have any audio going from my in office phones to the soft phone. I can call from soft phone extension to any internal extension and I can call from internal extension to my soft phone extension. I have my internal network as 10.0.0.0/24 and my VPN network 10.1.0.0/24, I have both in my PBX as trusted networks. I have the OpenVPN setup to NAT the information.
I have googled the for days now, and all I have come up with is that I should buy the VPN option on FreePBX. This will not work as I have to run software on my phone through the VPN and use the soft phone at the same time.

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Please use [Markdown](http://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts to improve their readability. A single paragraph is hard to read. That improves readability and attracts better answers which may help people with similar questions.

Comment: did you figure out the issue? are you using sip or pjsip? did you allow the rtp ports to pass through your openVPN server? openVPN setup to NAT? what are your local networks in freePBX sip settings?